# I accidentally disabled a game app, and want to enable it again

Tags: google-play-store

I have an app called `Episode Choose Your Story`. Every time I open it, it closes. I've tried unistalling and reinstalling it, but it's not working. I think it's disabled. How do I get it to work again?

Comment: No, it is not disabled, that's for sure. Only system apps can be disabled. User apps need root access to be disabled (freeze). Besides, you can't open a disabled app like the way you mentioned. There must be an issue with the app causing it to be closed. Contact its developer in that case.

Comment: Do you get Unfortunately this app has stopped working message? Or does the app closes without any messages? Are you using and Launcher applications?

Comment: Was this app working before you uninstalled it? I just wanna make sure that your phone meets the requirements to run the app properly.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when app gets updated, its hardware requirement, like more requirement of ram or better graphics, increaces which cause app to crash like you mentioned.